# Spaces of constant curvature

Tags: differential-geometry

Can someone please provide a reference for the theorem that states that, up to isometry, there are only three isotropic spaces of constant curvature, E^n, S^n and H^n, in any dimension.

Comment: As stated, this is false:  $\mathbb{R}P^n$ also has an isotropic metric of constant curvature.  I'm pretty sure that this is the only exception.  (It definitely is in the positive curvature setting).

Comment: I should have stated the theorem correctly. It says: For every real number K and every dimension n, there is only one simply connected, complete Riemannian manifold of dimension n and of constant sectional curvature K, up to isometry. Since rescaling the metric by t > 0, multiplies the curvature by 1/t^2, this leaves us with only 3 possible models for the space, according to whether the curvature is positive, 0 or negative.

Comment: Ah, this is proved in more or less every Riemannian geometry book.  For example, it's in Do Carmo's book on page 163.  It's on page 145 of Petersen's book.  Is this what you want?

Comment: Yes. Thanks. Is there an online reference where I can get this result from? I do not have these books.

Comment: Not that I know of....